# c# cannot write file in specific computer (Solved but don't know reason)

Tags: c#, windows, streamwriter

I have three computers for testing.

When I write files by my program in XP(PC, and it's my platform of developing) and Win7(PC), both are work.

But in one win7 computer(laptop), it cannot write and no exception come out.

Since Win 7(PC) can run my program perfectly, I think it's not the problem of win 7.

I find that when I use my c# program, it can read but cannot write file.

I try to set the path to c:/Users/Local/AppData and still doesn't work...

The permission to read and write can be accessed, and I can write file manually so maybe it's not because of memory leaking.

And I have tried to open my program in administrator mode.

I don't know any other reason why my program cannot write file in that computer.

I also tried to create directory as:

```
string appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(appDataPath, "test")))
{
   try
   {
       Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(appDataPath, "test"));
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("" + ex.ToString());
   }
}
```

The code can work in PC(XP and Win7), but still doesn't work in laptop(Win7)...

I also use `MessgeBox.Show` below the `CreateDirectory` method, and it can pop out the test message!( that is, the code of `CreateDirectory` is ran but when I look the parent directory, there isn't exist directory I want to create......( but in PC, the directory is created), I have seen someone have same problem, but the solution doesn't help me......

The code of writing file is:

```
try
{
     StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) + "\\logfile.txt");
     file.Write("test");
     file.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Why the strange laptop cannot write files by my program?

Edit:

My program have some operation in the textbox to record data to be saved,

the operation is: When user click at the textbox, the osk.exe( small keyboard) will show up. In my laptop, the osk.exe will show error when I want to run it......

The code to osk.exe is:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("" + System.Environment.SystemDirectory + "/osk.exe");
```

While I remove that code, the code to write file simply worked!

Maybe the reason is I check empty textbox first, then user click 'Save' button to write file. Since error occur when the code try to run osk.exe, the textbox may return null or something, then my code of write file won't be operated.

Comment: Make sure that you have write permissions and also check that if that directory is Read Only or not ?

Comment: I have seen the permissions, and I can write files manually.

Comment: maybe path from Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory is incorrect by some reason, check it.

Comment: If you don't get an exception then you can be sure that the directory was actually created.  Not being able to find it back is technically possible.  Run SysInternals' Process Monitor to see where it actually ended up.

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)` probably returns an empty string. So you've likely created the folder in your working directory instead of on the desktop.

Comment: Did you install **the same** .NET Framework version on all of your machines?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have tried to print the path to test where the directory is and it's what I want.

There is compact version of .Net Framework, I'm not sure it will have influence or not...( the version of the laptop is 4.5.1, but mine is 3.5, and there is .Net Compact Framework 3.5)

Comment: OK I think I get what you said about the OSK.exe; I had spent some time investigating an error while launcher osk.exe, and finally find out on Win7 64 bit there are two copies of osk.exe, on under the system32 dir and the other under SysWOW64 dir. If your program is a 32bit but tries to launch the one under system32, an error will occur.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's hardly possible but I had similar issue lately:

If you don't get an exception it can be caused by version mismatch of .NET Framework on your machines. This means that if some method got new overload that you're using and it's not implemented in previous version of .NET then it throws exception in the .NET internally while JIT compiler will try to compile the IL.

Had the same issue with the method PropertyInfo.GetValue(object) -> in previous version there was no such method but PropertyInfo.GetValue(object, object[])

Try to set (in the project properties) target framework that matches the framework you have installed on not working machine. If it compiles then you have to look for another solution.